# Rerender react native views on button click

Tags: react-native

I am working on my first react-native project and im trying to create a languege switch/toggle. I made a globals module which contains the current language and button text. Its working but the views are not rerendering. When i press save on any random place using expo the app wil reaload and show the new text. I have two diffenent json files, both another language.

In the header i have this button:

```
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => handleLangSelect()}>
    <MenuItem title={GLOBAL.button}/>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

and this action:

```
  const handleLangSelect = () => {
    if(GLOBAL.lang == "English"){
      GLOBAL.lang = "Dutch"
      GLOBAL.button = "ENG"
    }else{
      GLOBAL.lang = "English"
      GLOBAL.button = "NL"
    }
  }
```

and the homepage which will use the global to get the correct json.

```
function HomePage() {

  const GLOBAL = require('../globals/global');


  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
        <FlatList
          data={GLOBAL.lang == "Dutch" ? ArticlesNL : ArticlesENG}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <ArticleHome title={item.title} text={item.text} preview={item.preview} image={item.src} key={item.id} />
          }
        />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the useEffect hook to monitor the language change.

It should be something similar to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
}, [GLOBAl.lang]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've tried this but can get it to work but i see what you mean. Ill keep trying, i just read the docu about useEffect so lets give it another shot